# Can wireless extenders with the same network id interfere with each other?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I find myself to connect to wireless networks where the same network id is reused by multiple network extenders. Besides making troubleshooting harder, i wonder whether this could also create connectivity problems, since my client will find itself choosing between multiple access points whose power level might be close.

Is it possible that using the same id for multiple extenders creates interference or reduces performances? Does it make sense to set up different ids for every extender?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the same ID, and use the different repeater broadcast channels to select the one used.

Answer (score 0):

All the research i did suggests that extenders won't interfere with each other, however months of experience showed me how they do make troubleshooting harder.

One of the glitches i had was a laptop not automatically switching to the closer adapter while moving in a space. Having the same network id makes it harder to detect the issue and to manually select the closer one.

So my answer is: no, they cannot interfere with each other, but they can make troubleshooting harder. I suggest picking network ids that are meaningful to the users, while keeping the same password for all of them, for example:

```
lili-cafe-main
lili-cafe-extender-terrace
lili-cafe-extender-cellar
```